# GET parameters interfere with my plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I have my plugin all set-up using the Settings API and working but what I have is two manual functions in my plugin that can be run by the admin user by visiting the following URL's

```
<?php echo admin_url(); ?>options-general.php?page=wordpress-file-monitor-plus&sc_wpfmp_action=1&sc_wpfmp_scan=1
<?php echo admin_url(); ?>options-general.php?page=wordpress-file-monitor-plus&sc_wpfmp_action=1&sc_wpfmp_reset_settings=1
```

I'm using the `admin_init` hook to lookout for these GET parameters and do those functions.

The functions run fine and the user is back on my plugin settings page but the GET parameters are still in the URL. Not a big issue but if the user then goes ahead and save the settings those GET parameters are sent again and thus running those functions again.

Why does the Settings API send those parameters when submitting the settings form? The action of the form is to submit to `options.php`.

The only way around my issue I can think of is that after those manual functions have run its code in `admin_init` is to run a redirect to the settings page without the GET parameters, but if I do this I will lose my admin notices I'm trying to show to the user.

Anyway got any suggestions on how I can get around this problem. Maybe you think there is a better way to run these manual functions?

EDIT: full settings code: http://pastebin.com/Gk5RF5Lc

Comment: Seeing your code would help here.

Comment: @Bainternet I don't see how posting my code will help here. The code that runs said functions is not the issue. The issue is that the Settings API submits the GET parameters despite the form being set to submit to `options.php`. What seems to happen when the settings save is done it redirects back to where it came from, thus running my GET/functions again.

Comment: Seeing you could would help understand how you are showing your admin notices and how to keep them upon redirection.

Comment: @kaiser what's your problem with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the Settings API send those parameters when submitting the settings form?

Quite frankly, it doesn't. As you already mentioned, your form simply POST's to `options.php`, which in turn handles the request, updates the database, and then **redirects back to the referer**.

How the referer is fetched is down to the function `wp_get_referer()`;

```
function wp_get_referer() {
    $ref = '';
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer'] ) )
        $ref = $_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer'];
    else if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) )
        $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if ( $ref !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )
        return $ref;
    return false;
}
```

That's why you're getting sent back to your options page with the action parameters still there - because they were present in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

But you'll also see that you can override this behaviour, by placing a hidden input inside your form like so;

```
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="<?php echo admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=wordpress-file-monitor-plus' ); ?>" />
```

Now `options.php` will always redirect back to...

> http://example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wordpress-file-monitor-plus

...regardless of whatever was in the query string previously.

Comment: Sorry this wont work as `settings_fields("sc_wpfmp_settings");` auto adds `_wp_http_referer` to the form.

Comment: Just add `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( array( 'sc_wpfmp_action', 'sc_wpfmp_scan', 'sc_wpfmp_reset_settings' ) );` right before you call it :)

Comment: Thx TheDeadMedic. This solution works although I feel a bit hacky. I'd like to leave this question open for a bit longer to see if anyone else has any other solutions.

Comment: Admittedly it is - you can actually just place the input *after* the settings field - PHP will always take the 'last' value and override any others.